# css percentage width not working correctly when screen resizes

Tags: css, vb.net, mobile, resize

I am perplexed by what is happening when I resize the screen on our website.
I have been tasked to change the size of our search bar so that it will fill up most of the screen when we switch to mobile sized screens. When I hit a certain range of screen widths, the GO button drops down below the search text box. Below are screen shots, html and css. The other thing I don't understand is why this behavior was happening at all since I was using percentage widths. I thought I solved this by decreasing the percentage of the text as the screen width decreased. But when I do an inspect of the screen in Chrome, the problem goes away! Any insight as to why the percentage widths are not working like normal would be appreciated. Thanks.
[image]
[image]

```
    .mobilesearch .searchrow {
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        /*width: 650px !important;*/
        width: 94%!important;
        display: inline!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        /*width: 60px!important;*/
        width: 3%!important;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-top: 1px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1048px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 87%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 627px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 86%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 570px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 85%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 523px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 84%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 482px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 83%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 448px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 82%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 418px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 81%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 392px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 80%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 348px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 79%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 330px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        width: 78%!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 3%!important;
    }
}





          <!--Mobile-->
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelSearchMobile" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearchMobile" CssClass="row collapse search">
        &nbsp;<br />
        <div class="small-12 columns hideforhighres searchrow">

                            <asp:TextBox
                                ID="KeywordFieldMobile"
                                runat="server"
                                BackColor="white"
                                BorderColor="black"
                                ForeColor="black"
                                maxlength="100"
                                CssClass="headersearchbox"
                                placeholder="Search Products">
                            </asp:TextBox>

                           <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearchMobile" CssClass="searchbutton" 
                                runat="server" > Go</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
    <!--End of Mobile-->
```

Comment: You should probably use vw (viewport-width) and vh (viewport-height) instead of % on the parent elements to make it scale as you resize?

Comment: Or better! Just body{height:100vh;width:100vw} and hope that everything works and tweak it as it doesn't

Comment: Using width: 94vw; solved my problems! Thank you so much. I am still learning a lot about making pages adaptive to mobile and changing screen sizes. I was able to reduce the max-width adjustments to only 4 saving code.

Comment: No problem! Just keep making things and stay out of frameworks as long as you can!!! Adapting to front-end framworks is time consuming.. it took me 48 hours to convert small multipage website into singlepage application with vue but i wasn't too impressed so i took on react and it took me another 48 hours... getting sidetracked..  you should use vanilla languages as much as possible making anything for anyone and when you manage to make awesome stuff without looking something up from the web you are good to go trying new stuff. Before that i wouldn't recommend. Have fun coding! :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to J. Rajamaki for the suggestion of using vw instead of %. I learned a valuable technique and it worked fairly well. However, it was still not good enough for the person giving final approval. So I dug further and found the button was not changing size as I changed the screen width. What finally worked was determining the button width and subtracting that from the screen width as follows:

```
    .mobilesearch .searchrow {
    width: 100vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .headersearchbox {
        /*width: 650px !important;*/
        width: calc(100% - 64px)!important;
        display: inline!important;
    }
    .searchbutton {
        width: 64px!important;
        /*width: 3vw!important;*/
        display: inline;
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-top: 1px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-resolution: 96dpi) {
    .mobilesearch .searchrow {
        width: 99vw;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else with similar issues. For your own website I would try without the important tags. Our website is old and has many overrides requiring the important tags. The last change that tests for max-resolution: 96dpi is a trick to test for desktop instead of mobile devices. This reduces the encompassing div so that the vertical scroll bar does not cut off the GO button on a desktop screen that was resized. Mobile devices do not have the wide vertical scrollbar.